# Help proving a condition where the greatest lower bound of a set is equal to the least upper bound of another.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

So I'm  just not sure if the proof I have given for this claim is acceptable, and I was wondering if anyone could help me smooth it out. Thanks:

Let *E* be a nonempty subset of real numbers which is bounded below and let *F* be the set of all numbers $ -x $ such that $ x \in E $. Let $ \alpha_o $ be the greatest lower bound of *E* and let $ \beta_o $ be the least upper bound of *F*. Then: $ \alpha_o = -\beta_o$.

*Proof of claim.* If $ \alpha_o $ is the greatest lower bound of *E* then for every $ x \in E $, $ \alpha_o\leq x $. Then, by the properties of the ordered field $ \mathbb R $, for every $ -x \in F $, $ -\alpha_o\geq -x $. So $ -\alpha_o $ is an upper bound of *F* and $ \beta_o \leq -\alpha_o $, or rather, $ -\beta_o \geq \alpha_o $.

Similarly, if $ \beta_o $ is the least upper bound of *F* then for every $ -x \in F $, $ \beta_o \geq -x $. Then, by the properties of the ordered field $ \mathbb R $, for every $ x \in E $, $ -\beta_o\leq x $. So $ -\beta_o $ is a lower bound of $ E $ and $ -\beta_o \leq \alpha_o $.

This proves the claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's perfect. $             $

Comment: I was just worried that I couldn't say that: "if for every $ x \in E$, $ \alpha_o\leq x $ then for every $ -x \in F $, $ -\alpha_o\geq -x $."

Comment: Of course you can. The justification depends on how you have defined/constructed the real numbers. This is how I would justify it: You have $\alpha_0\leq x$; by definition, this is $x-\alpha_0\geq0$; then $-(x-\alpha_0)\leq0$, and this is $-x\leq-\alpha_0$.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin.